# when i try to compile i keep getting message vector subscript out of range

Tags: c++, exception, vector, subscript

```
string getName()  { return name; }
string getE1()  { return enemy1; }
string getE2()  { return enemy2; }
string getE3()  { return enemy3; }

bool isEnemy(string check) {
    if (check == enemy1 || check == enemy2 || check == enemy3)
```

//if the name being checked is an enemy of this knight
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

```
int Candidate(Knight b) {//'b' is an enemy of 'a' who is in the seat before 'b'(ie. b seat=2 a seat=1
    int toSwap = b.seatingPos;//toSwap holds seating pos # of 'b'
    int checkFriends = (toSwap - 1);//holds seating pos of 'a'
    string nameA = table[checkFriends].getName();
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        if (table[i].isEnemy(nameA) || table[i].getName() == nameA) //if not enemies, then must be friends
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            friends.push_back(table[i].seatingPos);
        }//adds seating # of friends of 'a' to friends vector

    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {//check friends of 'a' to see if their neighbor is friends with 'b'
        int check2 = table[friends[j]].seatingPos;//check 2 holds seating pos # of 'c'
        if (check2 != 7)
            ++check2;
        else
            return check2;
        if ((table[toSwap].isEnemy(table[check2].getName()))) //if neighbor of c is friends with b(toSwap)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else {
            return check2;//if not enemies then must be friends return seating pos of acceptable candidate

        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

when i debug the code it says i have an unhandled exception when assigning
 string nameA = table[checkFriends].getName();
the value of checkfriends = 0 so it shouldnt be out of the range of the vector.

debugger also says: Unhandled exception at 0x7BC8F2F6 (ucrtbased.dll) in Knights.exe: An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal. occurred
this occurs during the 1st if statement.
thanks for any help!!!

Comment: On the line before put in `assert(checkFriends >= 0 && checkFriends < table.size());`

Comment: How do you know that the value of checkFriends is zero? Are you sure that table is not zero size? Something doesn't add up here.

Comment: thanks john! i fed both table and friend vectors as a parameter to the function and it resolved my issue!